# How resize UE4 TArray in UKismetArrayLibrary::Array_Resize?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

There is an array TArray<AItem*> Items (AItem is child of an AActor), need to do resize Items in UKismetArrayLibrary::Array_Resize(const TArray< int32 >& TargetArray,    int32 Size), but Array_Resize does not accept TArray<AItem*> Items because of a different data type. In BP Array_Resize function is doing great for for all array-type. How Array_Resize must work in C++?

Comment: If you’re writing C++ code, why would you use blueprint support functions to resize the array? Why not use the C++ methods for that directly?

Comment: I am adapting the BP project for c++ and part of the functionality in the BP project is made using UKismetArrayLibrary. And in general, I want to find out why it works just in the BP version and is absolutely incomprehensible in the c++ version..

Comment: That is most likely not the function that blueprint really uses. Although I unfortunately don't have unreal with me to find the right one. Anyway, the real answer is it probably uses a UK2 node and holds pointers to each element instead of the data itself (C++ requires compile time knowledge of types to automatically allocate objects of them which it can't get from blueprint). Unless you're nativizing the blueprints but this is another story.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer. There were such thoughts about internal functions, misleading that these functions are available from c++.

Comment: What do you expect those Blueprint Nodes are coming from? Everything you can do in BP can be done in C++, but not vice versa. What you are probably searching for is [TArray<T>::SetNum()](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TArray/SetNum/).

Comment: Thx Max Play, its right.

Answer (score 0):

TArray::SetNum() is be the answer. Thanks to all!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).